# TypeError at /check-out getting dict value but i want both dict and also specified value

Tags: python, django

When i checkout an order i got this error.I am passing a dict in customer object but whenever i remove dict function i cant login anymore. i cant also fetch customer details.

Here is my views.py(i think my problems are in these views only):

```
class Login(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'signupsignin/signin.html')

    def post(self, request):
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        customer = Customer.get_customer(phone_number)
        error_message = None
        if customer:
            match = check_password(password, customer.password)
            if match:
                customer.__dict__.pop('_state')
                request.session['customer'] = customer.__dict__
                #request.session['csutomer'] = customer.id
                return redirect('Home')
            else:
                error_message = 'Phone number or Password didnt match on our record'
        else:
            error_message = 'No Customer Found! Please Registrer First!'
        print(phone_number, password)
        context = {'error_message': error_message}
        return render(request, 'signupsignin/signin.html', context)
class Checkout(View):
    def post(self, request):
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        customer = request.session.get('customer')
        products = Product.get_products_id(list(cart.keys()))

        print(fname, phone, address, products, cart, customer)

        for product in products:
            order = Order(customer=Customer(id=customer), product=product, fname=fname,
                          price=product.price, phone=phone, address=address, quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))

            order.save()

        request.session['cart'] = {}

        return redirect('cart')
```

Here is my urls.py for these function:

```
path('login', Login.as_view(), name='login'),
path('check-out', Checkout.as_view(), name="check-out"),
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError at /check-out
Field 'id' expected a number but got {'id': 3, 'phone_number': '01622153196', 'email': 'sakibovi@gmail.com', 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$216000$H2o5Do81kxI0$2tmMwSnSJHBVBTU9tQ8/tkN7h1ZQpRKrTAKkax1xp2Y=', 'coin': 1200.0}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is at this line:

```
order = Order(customer=Customer(id=customer), product=product, fname=fname,
                          price=product.price, phone=phone, address=address, quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))
```

try to change `customer` to a `customer.id` like this:

```
order = Order(customer=Customer(id=customer.id), product=product, fname=fname,
                          price=product.price, phone=phone, address=address, quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))
```

You are passing the full `customer` object there where you expect just its id.

---

If it does't help you than please try also this:

```
order = Order(customer=customer, product=product, fname=fname,
                          price=product.price, phone=phone, address=address, quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))
```

According to your error, I assume you can directly assign customer objects to the `customer` column while instantiating an `order` object.